# How do you create a local variable inside ngFor

Tags: angular, ionic2

How do I grab a snapshot of a class inside `*ngFor` to save time/state/humanized values in a local variable?

For example, `timer.remaining = timer.expires - Date.now()`

```
<ion-card  class="timer" *ngFor="let timer of timers"> 
  <ion-card-content>
    <ion-card-title>{{timer.humanize(timer.remaining) }}</ion-card-title>
    <div class="card-subtitle">{{timer.label}}</div>
  </ion-card-content>
  <ion-note>remaining: {{timer.remaining/1000}}</ion-note>
  <button ion-button block icon-left 
    [color]="lookup[timer.state].color" 
    (click)="timerClick(timer)"
  >
    <ion-icon [name]="lookup[timer.state].icon" ></ion-icon>
    {{timer.label}}
  </button>
</ion-card>
```

I want to call `timer.snapshot()` just once inside `ngFor` to get all display properties.

**Solution:**

thanks, I used a pipe to transform `Timers` then pushed it through `*ngFor`

```
// Pipe
@Pipe({name: 'toJSON', pure: false})
export class ToJsonPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any| Array<any>): any | Array<any> { 
    let unwrap = false;
    if (!Array.isArray(value)) {
      value = [value];
      unwrap = true;
    }
    const result = value.map( (o)=>{
      if (o && o.toJSON) return o.toJSON(); 
      else return {};
    })
    return unwrap ? result[0] : result;
  }
}



// html template
<ion-card  class="timer" *ngFor="let timer of timers | toJSON ">
```

Comment: The best way to do this is to create pipe which will calculate remaining time for you. I think, all other approaches would be hacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create an array of values you want to use with `*ngFor` in the components class or a service and then just bind to that using `*ngFor` instead of putting logic into `*ngFor` itself. 
There might be hacks but they usually work poorly with Angulars change detection and will probably hurt your components performance a lot.

Comment: I used the solution above, and it sort of works. However, SimpleChange is not storing the previousValue correctly, it is always `{}`. It might be caused by returning anonymous objects from the Pipe, but I don't know the solution. see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42134483/angular2-simplechange-is-not-storing-previousvalue

Comment: I couldn't find anything about `SimpleChange` in your question.

Comment: Not in this question, but the solution of creating an array of objects solves the `ngFor` problem but creates another problem when you want to bind a component attr to the `ngFor` template input variable. The change detection loop doesn't handle it cleanly.

Comment: I guess it would be best to cteate a new question with the code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish and what issue you run into.

Comment: Did that in the comment. Just wanted to ask if you had come across the issue. I can't be the first one...

Comment: Sorry, but I have no idea how `SimpleChanges` could be involved or what you mean by the rest of the comment.